# Any way to save format when importing an excel file in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm doing some work on the data in an excel sheet using python pandas. When I write and save the data it seems that pandas only saves and cares about the raw data on the import. Meaning a lot of stuff I really want to keep such as cell colouring, font size, borders, etc get lost. Does anyone know of a way to make pandas save such things?

From what I've read so far it doesn't appear to be possible. The best solution I've found so far is to use the xlsxwriter to format the file in my code before exporting. This seems like a very tedious task that will involve a lot of testing to figure out how to achieve the various formats and aesthetic changes I need. I haven't found anything but would said writer happen to in any way be able to save the sheet format upon import?

Alternatively, what would you suggest I do to solve the problem that I have described?

Answer (score 0):

Separate data from formatting. Have a sheet that contains only the data – that's the one you will be reading/writing to – and another that has formatting and reads the data from the first sheet.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Can I achieve this in python/pandas though? Or is that something I will have to do in excel?

Comment: The way I see it: you prepare an excel file with two sheets and then overwrite values inside the 'data' sheet